# Publish all changes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a Rails app where an admin is able to create and edit records in the database, so he/she is working on a list of records. While the admin is editing the records, these changes shouldn't be visible on the public site yet, but only after the admin clicks on a 'publish all' button. 
Is it possible to keep the records in memory but not saving them to the database, until the publish button is clicked? The admin should be able to navigate between index and show pages while he/she is working on the records.

Thanks in advance,

Rens

Comment: Can you add a published field to the table?  Then you just show the published records to users.

Comment: That's possible, but what if a record already exists, and the admin is editing it? In that case, I would like to show the existing state on the public site until the admin clicks on 'publish all'

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but is there state where the edits are saved but not published yet?

Comment: Well, if the admin navigates between the edit/show pages of the records, he/she will see the changes (in the admin panel). These changes shouldn't be visible on the public site yet. So, yes they are saved in some way (in memory for example).

Answer (score 0):

In order to share an information between users (living in different processes) you need to store it somewhere. The best way is a database.

I suggest you to store the information in the database and add a `published` boolean attribute. Then make sure to select for public view only the published records.

Comment: That's possible, but what if a record already exists, and the admin is editing it? In that case, I would like to show the existing state on the public site until the admin clicks on 'publish all'